# Removing the state database from the ledger in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the fabric documentation it says that the state database is an indexed view of the chain of transactions and that it is not necessary since it can always be rebuilt from the chain.

Since in the project that I'm doing there will be a large number of assets, and the latest value of these assets will be persisted in the state database, that would cause a fairly large memory overhead. Majority of the peers will not need to query the state.

So my question is if there is a way to disable state database(world state) on some peers and have them only maintain the chain?

Answer (score 1):

The state database is necessary for transaction executions, and transactions rely on the state db to generate read-write sets, so it is not possible to disable them.

To look from another angle, the existence of state db makes the transactions faster because the other option would be to check all the committed transactions in the actual ledger every time a new transaction needs to executed. This scenario can be extremely slow depending on the size of the ledger.